# How filter json data with date from datepicker Angular2 app

Tags: json, angular, highcharts, datepicker

I have Angular 2 app where i use angular2-highcharts.
I get data from json for highcharts but I would like filter which data will be use in charts by start and end date.
Can somebody help me with this question, or give me link for tutorial or something where I can find information about that.

I use mydaterangepicker and there is service for getting data from json:

```
    @Injectable()
export class ValuesService {

  http: Http;
  constructor(http: Http) {
      this.http = http;
  }

    getValues(beginDate: Date, endDate: Date):
        Observable<Values> {
        return this.http.get('http://localhost:54122/api/ProductionValues/GetProductionValuesDATETIME?startDate=' + beginDate +'&endDate=' + endDate)
            .map(this.extractData)
            .catch(this.handleError)
    }

    private extractData(res: Response) {
        let body = res.json();
        return body || {};
    }

    private handleError(error: any) {
        // // In a real world app, we might use a remote logging infrastructure
        // // We'd also dig deeper into the error to get a better message
        let errMsg = (error.message) ? error.message :
            error.status ? `${error.status} - ${error.statusText}` : 'Server error';
        console.error(errMsg); // log to console instead
        return Observable.throw(errMsg);
}
```

Comment: Is this is question about angular2, cause you pass range params to the server api, maybe you should handle filtration there?

Comment: I want choose date range in app with datepicker

Comment: Your server should handle this, accept these params & return only those values or return all your data & filter it on client side(which is not a good option).
As per your API your server should return the filtered data.

Comment: I choose beginDate and endDate in mydaterangepicker so I have two value 2016-10-06, 2016-10-13 and how can I give this value to me service where i want have this url:
<code>http://localhost:54122/api/ProductionValues/GetProductionValuesDATETIME?startDate=2016-10-06&endDate=2016-10-13</code>

Comment: You should get range values from datepicker via their api, then parse it to Date type and pass to your service endpoint

Comment: Additionally, In Highcharts you can use setExtremes for setting extremes of your axis to specific range: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Axis.setExtremes but it will not filter your data.

Answer (score 0):

The issues is the `res.json()` returns dates as strings.  I ended up changing my mapping for http get calls in my app to look something like this:

```
.map(res => {
            let jsonData = res.json();
            for (let obj of jsonData) {
                for (let prop in obj) {
                    if (moment(obj[prop], moment.ISO_8601).isValid()) {
                        obj[prop] = new Date(obj[prop]);
                    }
                }
            }
            return jsonData;
      })
```

Basically, this uses momentjs to convert any strings of a valid format to an actual date object instead of a string.  You may need to change the format parameter depending on how the data is being returned from the server.

Also, note you will need to do a `npm install moment` on your project and `import * as moment from 'moment';` on your component to make this work.